# FocusNode - Why is requestFocus() not working?

Tags: flutter

The following is the relevant code. The debugPrint() in the onFieldSubmitted: is running, so the code is getting here, but the focus is not changing. Focus does not change.

```
 _createItemHeadingWidget() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controllerItemHed,
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: _focusNodeItemHed,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
          debugPrint("ItemHeading submitted");
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodeItemDetail);
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Item Heading",
          hintText: "Enter item heading",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
  Widget _createItemDetailWidget() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controllerItemDetail,
        maxLength: 75,
        focusNode: _focusNodeItemDetail,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
          debugPrint("ItemDetail submitted");
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodeItemPrice);
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Item Detail",
          hintText: "Enter item detail",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
class DataEntryState extends State<DataEntry> {
  final TextEditingController _controllerItemHed = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerItemDetail = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerItemPrice = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerSeller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerContactNr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controllerLocation = TextEditingController();

  final FocusNode _focusNodeItemHed = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNodeItemDetail = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNodeItemPrice = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNodeSeller = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNodeContactNr = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focusNodeLocation = FocusNode();
```

Comment: Try using `_focusNode.unfocus()` before `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nextFocusNode)`

Comment: Try initialize the value on `initState()`

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions, but they did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After trying many things that did not work, the only solution that I could find is as follows:

```
  _changeFocus(BuildContext context, FocusNode focusNodeCurrent,
      FocusNode focusNodeNext) {
    focusNodeCurrent.unfocus();
    setState(() => _focusNodeCurrent = focusNodeNext);
  }
```

debugPrint() showed that in _changeFocus(), unfocus() does work, and that requestFocus() did not work.

In the build :

```
    if (_focusNodeCurrent != null)
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodeCurrent);
```

Other relevant code (some of which is probably redundant) :

```
 TextFormField _createItemHeadingWidget(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).reparentIfNeeded(_focusNodeItemHed);
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controllerItemHed,
      maxLength: 50,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autofocus: _dataRec == null,
      focusNode: _focusNodeItemHed,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
        _changeFocus(context, _focusNodeItemHed, _focusNodeItemDetail);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Item Heading",
        hintText: "Enter item heading",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

instead of

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

Comment: Or can use 
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(<your assigned focusNode>);

Gave upvote on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
firstFieldFocusNode.nextFocus();
```

Did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Use this when calling =>

```
FocusNode _focusNodeItemDetail = FocusNode();

_changeFocus(){
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50),(){
             FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodeItemDetail);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing setState() to solve this problem didn't seem to me like the optimum solution, so I kept testing. After a lot of further testing which mainly involved removing everything that I could from the app, I eventually replaced the creation of MaterialApp with creation of Scaffold. This fixed the problem. Now it appears to work as intended. All that is required is to do is:

```
 _changeFocus(BuildContext context, FocusNode focusNodeNew) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNodeNew);
  }
```

I presume that the reason I was initially creating a MaterialApp is that I copied that from another app when I was initially starting to learn Flutter. It appears that it's not necessary to create a MaterialApp, but I don't know the reasons for creating a MaterialApp as opposed to creating just the Scaffold.

Whether it is a bug in flutter that causes this behavior, I don't know. It may be just a "feature" of using MaterialApp, or perhaps I was misusing MaterialApp.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this I was just playing around and made a demo.

[image]

You can switch the focus to the left or right textfields or cancel the focus. The code below is a combination of @Brian Oh 's answers and some new code. Features:

- keeps track of all nodes including no focus and current focus
- changeFocus function only requires nextFocus parameter, doesn't use `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nextFocusNode)` and doesn't have to set state

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home(),);
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {

  FocusNode currentFocusNode;
  FocusNode leftFocusNode;
  FocusNode rightFocusNode;
  FocusNode noFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentFocusNode = FocusNode();
    leftFocusNode = FocusNode();
    rightFocusNode = FocusNode();
    noFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //currentFocusNode.dispose();
    //leftFocusNode.dispose();
    //rightFocusNode.dispose();
    //noFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  changeFocus(FocusNode focusNodeNext) {
    currentFocusNode.unfocus();
    focusNodeNext.requestFocus();
    currentFocusNode = focusNodeNext;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [

            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container( width: 50, child: TextField(
                  focusNode: leftFocusNode,
                ),),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('^ Focus ^'),
                  onPressed: () => changeFocus(leftFocusNode),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container( width: 50, child: TextField(
                  focusNode: rightFocusNode,
                ),),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('^ Focus ^'),
                  onPressed: () => changeFocus(rightFocusNode),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('  Cancel Focus'),
              onPressed: () => changeFocus(noFocusNode),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### EDIT:

I used this code in another app and got an error

> A FocusNode was used after being disposed.

according to [this github link](https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_keyboard_actions/issues/22) you should't call dispose. I've commented out the dispose calls made to focus nodes above and the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Using `FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus()` has worked for me

**Custom Widget Code I Used**

````
CupertinoTextFormFieldRow customTextField(
  String pretext, String supportText,
  TextEditingController controller, Function(String) validatorFun) {
  return CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
    controller: controller,
    prefix: Text(pretext),
    placeholder: supportText,
    validator: (val) => validatorFun(val!),
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    onEditingComplete: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
    },
  );
}```
````